# how to find function in shared library from application crash log

Tags: linux, crash, shared-libraries

Here is part of output from kernel log after application crash:

```
kernel: [  252.772000] testsnd/972: potentially unexpected fatal signal 11.
...
kernel: [  252.788000] PC is at 0x296313a4
...
kernel: [  252.820000] mmap = 0x00400000->testsnd 0x29558000->ld-2.10.1.so 0x29580000->libpthread-2.10.1.so 0x295a8000->libdl-2.10.1.so 0x295bc000->librt-2.10.1.so 0x295d4000->libc-2.10.1.so
```

application has crashed in libc.
How to obtain function name where crash had appeared using this information (`0x295d4000->libc-2.10.1.so` and PC is at `0x296313a4`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the offsets of each function in the .so using objdump. I typically just use the -S switch, as it will show source when you have it, and will do a basic disassembly as well.

```
objdump -SR /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
```

If you know the base addr the library is loaded at, you can then compute the actual locations.

Comment: "If you know the base addr ..." That's *exactly* what the kernel message supplied. The address `0x296313a4` apparently maps into `libc-2.10.1.so`, which was loaded at `0x295d4000`.

Comment: This is perfect, I used objdump -x and -d before, but -SR is much better, it even shows me the C++ code when I have debug turned on!

Answer (score 1):

The library loaded at the highest address is `libc-2.10.1.so` at `0x295d4000`.

```
perl -e 'printf "0x%x\n", 0x296313a4 - 0x295d4000'
0x5d3a4

addr2line -fe /lib/libc.so.6 0x5d3a4
```

... should print function name (and file/line info if you have libc debuginfo package installed). You may have to substitue `/lib/libc.so.6` with actual location of 64-bit `libc.so.6` on your system.

Comment: @Andy Using `nm -D` on libc.so.6 will tell you the function (the address, 0x5d3a4 in this case, is within one). This is determinable even without debug info; though for more exact specification of where PC lies, you will indeed need the debug info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys.
I am sure answers can help other programmers.
But in my case problem seems to be more platform specific (sh4 ST-Linux).
Therefore question shall be asked at ST website or bugzilla.